# How to create a custom yaml config file in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, configuration-files, yaml, symfony-1.4

What I want to do is quite simple: store data in a custom config file that I want to read later on.

I created my file `something.yml` that I put in the global `config` directory.
It looks like that:

```
prod:
  test:  ok

dev:
  test: ko

all:
  foo:  bar
  john: doe
```

Then I copied the config_handlers.yml and also put it in the config directory and added the following at the top of the file:

```
config/something.yml:
  class:    sfDefineEnvironmentConfigHandler
  param:
    prefix: something_
```

But if I'm calling `sfConfig::get("something_foo");` I keep getting `NULL`.

What did I do wrong?
I just want to read values, so no need to create a custome config handler, right?

I've read the doc here: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files even though I'm running 1.4 (I don't think that changed since then).

**Edit:** Of course I can use `sfYaml::load()` but I'd like to do things in a better way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you use the custom config file for that's different from the functionality that existing config files already offer? If it's just simple data, what's wrong with app.yml? or a custom class in /lib/?

Comment: app.yml would work fine. But we're talking about a lot of data here. I would just like to keep things separated.

Comment: I see.... the YAML format is quite anal to maintain, so personally I wouldn't go down this route at all for storing data but I suppose you have your reasons.

Comment: @Tom: Yaml files rock, just glorified arrays. I love XML as well, but IMO Yaml files are far cleaner and easier to work with when using them as configuration setups.

Answer (score 12):

Do not modify the index.php this is dirty!

Juste add this line to your app/frontend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php

```
require_once($this->getConfigCache()->checkConfig('config/something.yml'));
```

(adapt with your own app name)

Answer (score 5):

It's really easy, but also a little bit hacky:

Create the file `/config/config_handlers.yml` and add this:

```
config/something.yml:
  class:    sfDefineEnvironmentConfigHandler
  param:
    prefix: something_
```

Then add these two lines to `/web/index.php` after `... getApplicationConfiguration()` (and also add them to frontend_dev.php and wherever you want this config file to be available):

```
$configCache = new sfConfigCache($configuration);
include($configCache->checkConfig('config/something.yml'));
```

So your `/web/index.php` might look like this afterwards:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
$configCache = new sfConfigCache($configuration);
$configCache->checkConfig('config/something.yml');
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Btw: This is also in the documentation you cited, although the checkConfig() call is in a different place. Look for this: "When you need the code based on the map.yml file and generated by the myMapConfigHandler handler in your application, call the following line:"

Have fun ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this **for a plugin** you need to load the configuration file in the initialize() method. You can still use config_handlers.yml in your plugin's config directory or let the plugin load the handler too.

```
class myPluginConfiguration extends sfPluginConfiguration
{
  public function setup() // loads handler if needed
  {
    if ($this->configuration instanceof sfApplicationConfiguration)
    {
      $configCache = $this->configuration->getConfigCache();
      $configCache->registerConfigHandler('config/features.yml', 'sfDefineEnvironmentConfigHandler',
        array('prefix' => 'feature_'));
      $configCache->checkConfig('config/features.yml');
    }
  }

  public function initialize() // loads the actual config file
  {
    if ($this->configuration instanceof sfApplicationConfiguration)
    {
      $configCache = $this->configuration->getConfigCache();
      include($configCache->checkConfig('config/features.yml'));
    }
  }
}
```

The plugin's config initialize() method is called automatically by sfProjectConfiguration class and all appConfiguration classes (trough inheritance).

Comment: I'm sure that this is a nice way to include (custom) yml-files, though I have a `sfProjectConfiguration` in stead of a `sfApplicationConfiguration`. Do you happen to know how to include it in that way?

Answer (score 1):

if your cached config-file is empty, you have probably forgotten to set the environment in your yml-file.

like:

```
all:
  test:  value1
  test2: value2

dev:
  test2: value3
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in all application files:

```
$configCache = sfApplicationConfiguration::getActive()->getConfigCache();
$configCache->registerConfigHandler('config/something.yml', 'sfDefineEnvironmentConfigHandler', Array('prefix' => 'something_'));
include $configCache->checkConfig('config/something.yml');
```

Then you can use:

```
sfConfig::get("something_foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache files?

```
php symfony cc
```

In prodution environment all config files, classes, etc... are being cached.