# Accessing project settings in a symfony task

Tags: symfony1, yaml

I have set up some custom symfony project-level settings in the file `config/project.yml` following the suggestion in [How to manage your own cross-apps/global configuration values](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToHandleCrossAppsConfigurationFiles). Following these instructions I added the line

```
require_once sfConfigCache::getInstance()->checkConfig('config/project.yml');
```

to the `configure` method of my `client` application's `clientConfiguration.class.php` file.

I then created a new symfony task using `php symfony generate:task`. In this new task I want to access the settings in the `config/project.yml` file. Here is the execute portion of the task:

```
protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array()){
  // initialize the database connection
  $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
  $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();

  $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('client', 'test', true);

  echo sfConfig::get('project_mail_webmaster') . "\n" ;
}
```

However, when I run the task I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method sfConfigCache::getInstance() in /opt/sfproject/apps/client/config/clientConfiguration.class.php on line 7
```

http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToHandleCrossAppsConfigurationFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was already answered in Stackoverflow in [How to create a custom yaml config file in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544553/how-to-create-a-custom-yaml-config-file-in-symfony).